# Prove that every group of order 77 must have an element of order 7 and order 11.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

I need to prove this without Sylows Theorems or Normal subgroups (nor Cauchy's Theorem). I believe much of the answer lies in Lagrange's Theorem, but I can't quite find it.

Comment: Can you use Cauchy's Theorem?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_theorem_(group_theory)

Comment: I cannot use Cauchy's Theorem

Comment: Might as well just prove Cauchy's theorem from scratch and then use it.

Comment: My Professor explicitly told us to not use Cauchy's theorem

Comment: If $G$ has an element of order $77$ you are done. So assume $G$ has no such elements. Try to find a contradiction if all elements have order $7$.

Comment: My guess is that you are to make the observation that the number of elements of order seven must be a multiple of six, and the number of elements of order eleven is a multiple of ten. As 76 is neither, both must occur.

Comment: But I'm not sure whether that is more elementary than Cauchy. The two results are very nearly at the same level (and often covered during the same week). Also, I'm sure we have had very closely related threads in the past...

Comment: See [David's answer here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1577814/11619). And there's also [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/661610/11619).